# Pivot? Case? I'm not sure how to proceed

Tags: sql, oracle

Using Oracle DB. I'm trying to take data in one column (ts.name) and make that data the column names and make the data in another column (sts.numscore) the data for the column (ts.name). I'm using CASE statements but it's not working. The CASE statements are putting one test score per row. I need all the test scores on one row. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
SELECT schools.name AS School,
  s.lastfirst AS Student,
  s.student_number,
  s.grade_level,
  t.name AS Test_Name,
  (case when ts.name = 'ACT_Reading' then sts.numscore end) as ACT_Reading,
  (case when ts.name = 'ACT_Math' then sts.numscore end) as ACT_Math,
  (case when ts.name = 'ACT_English' then sts.numscore end) as ACT_English,
  (case when ts.name = 'ACT_Science' then sts.numscore end) as ACT_Science,
  (case when ts.name = 'ACT_Composite' then sts.numscore end) as ACT_Composite,
  to_char (st.test_date),
  sts.numscore AS Score 
FROM students s,studenttestscore sts,studenttest st,test t,testscore ts,schools
WHERE s.id = sts.studentid
AND sts.studenttestid = st.id
AND sts.testscoreid = ts.id
AND ts.testid = t.id
AND s.schoolid = schools.school_number
AND t.name = 'ACT'
AND sts.numscore > 0 
and s.enroll_status=0
AND s.schoolid=10
ORDER BY s.lastfirst,st.test_date DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the results in a single row you need to aggregate the results of the case expressions; something like:

```
SELECT schools.name AS School,
  s.lastfirst AS Student,
  s.student_number,
  s.grade_level,
  t.name AS Test_Name,
  max(case when ts.name = 'ACT_Reading' then sts.numscore end) as ACT_Reading,
  max(case when ts.name = 'ACT_Math' then sts.numscore end) as ACT_Math,
  max(case when ts.name = 'ACT_English' then sts.numscore end) as ACT_English,
  max(case when ts.name = 'ACT_Science' then sts.numscore end) as ACT_Science,
  max(case when ts.name = 'ACT_Composite' then sts.numscore end) as ACT_Composite,
  to_char (st.test_date)
FROM students s,studenttestscore sts,studenttest st,test t,testscore ts,schools
WHERE s.id = sts.studentid
AND sts.studenttestid = st.id
AND sts.testscoreid = ts.id
AND ts.testid = t.id
AND s.schoolid = schools.school_number
AND t.name = 'ACT'
AND sts.numscore > 0 
and s.enroll_status=0
AND s.schoolid=10
GROUP BY schools.name,
  s.lastfirst,
  s.student_number,
  s.grade_level,
  t.name,
  st.test_date
ORDER BY s.lastfirst, st.test_date DESC
```

As you're effectively pivoting the score, you don't want to include that as its own column, in the select list or the group-by.

It would be better to use modern join syntax, instead of the ancient comma-separated list of tables in the `from` clause; and you should also supply the format model in the `to_char()` call for the date:

```
SELECT schools.name AS school,
  s.lastfirst AS student,
  s.student_number,
  s.grade_level,
  t.name AS test_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ts.NAME = 'ACT_Reading' THEN sts.numscore END) AS act_reading,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ts.NAME = 'ACT_Math' THEN sts.numscore END) AS act_math,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ts.NAME = 'ACT_English' THEN sts.numscore END) AS act_english,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ts.NAME = 'ACT_Science' THEN sts.numscore END) AS act_science,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ts.NAME = 'ACT_Composite' THEN sts.numscore END) AS act_composite,
  to_char(st.test_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS test_date
FROM students s
JOIN studenttestscore sts ON s.id = sts.studentid
JOIN studenttest st ON sts.studenttestid = st.id
JOIN testscore ts ON sts.testscoreid = ts.id
JOIN test t ON ts.testid = t.id
JOIN schools ON s.schoolid = schools.school_number
WHERE t.name = 'ACT'
AND sts.numscore > 0 
and s.enroll_status=0
AND s.schoolid=10
GROUP BY schools.name,
  s.lastfirst,
  s.student_number,
  s.grade_level,
  t.name,
  st.test_date
ORDER BY s.lastfirst, st.test_date DESC
```

An equivalent using `pivot` would be something like:

```
SELECT school, student, student_number, grade_level, test_name,
  act_reading, act_math, act_english, act_science, act_composite,
  to_char(test_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS test_date
FROM (
  SELECT schools.name AS school,
    s.lastfirst AS student,
    s.student_number,
    s.grade_level,
    t.name AS test_name,
    ts.name AS test_score_name,
    sts.numscore,
    st.test_date
  FROM students s
  JOIN studenttestscore sts ON s.id = sts.studentid
  JOIN studenttest st ON sts.studenttestid = st.id
  JOIN testscore ts ON sts.testscoreid = ts.id
  JOIN test t ON ts.testid = t.id
  JOIN schools ON s.schoolid = schools.school_number
  WHERE t.name = 'ACT'
  AND sts.numscore > 0 
  AND s.enroll_status=0
  AND s.schoolid=10
)
PIVOT (
  max(numscore)
  FOR test_score_name IN (
    'ACT_Reading' AS act_reading,
    'ACT_Math' AS act_math,
    'ACT_English' AS act_english,
    'ACT_Science' AS act_science,
    'ACT_Composite' AS act_composite
  )
) p
ORDER BY p.student, p.test_date DESC
```

but it would be translated to the aggregate/case version under the hood anyway.

(All untested of course, as we don't have your schema to play with...)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your first query worked!!! Thank you! I tried the joins but no data was returned.

Comment: @JBrown - like I said, untested... but you should have been getting errors rather that no results, is your client/application suppressing them somehow? I had kept the joins in the same order you listed the tables originally, but two of them needed to be swapped over.

Comment: I'm using SQL Dev. I also have another problem if you can help that would be awesome. I need to total the 5 columns in the CASE statements and add a "Total" column. I've tried couple of ways but no luck. Thank you!

Comment: If you're using either of the first two queries you can just add `SUM(sts.numscore) AS total`. If there are test score names that you want to exclude (other than five you've shown) then you can either add a filter or make that sum conditional. With the real pivot version you can add the columns together - though you may need to coalesce them with zero if any can be null. If you try and get really stuck then ask a new question.

Comment: I added the column but the sum is wrong on some records but right on others?

770 750 (null) 3040

720 790 (null) 1510

Comment: It appears to be doubling the scores on some records?

max(case when ts.name = 'Reading' then sts.numscore end) as Reading,
  max(case when ts.name = 'Math' then sts.numscore end) as Math,
  max(case when ts.name = 'Writing' then sts.numscore end) as Writing,
  SUM(sts.numscore) as Total,

Comment: You may have duplicate records from the main part of the query then. If you change `max(case...` to `sum(case...` as a test, do the numbers then match? If so you'll need to figure out where the duplicates are coming from. (Or you don't only have those five names...)

Comment: You were right again! There was another test score and after I exclude it the total scores were correct!!! Thank you so much for your help. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use conditional aggregation like below-

```
SELECT schools.name AS School,
  s.lastfirst AS Student,
  s.student_number,
  s.grade_level,
  t.name AS Test_Name,
  max(case when ts.name = 'ACT_Reading' then sts.numscore end) as ACT_Reading,
  max(case when ts.name = 'ACT_Math' then sts.numscore end) as ACT_Math,
  max(case when ts.name = 'ACT_English' then sts.numscore end) as ACT_English,
  max(case when ts.name = 'ACT_Science' then sts.numscore end) as ACT_Science,
  max(case when ts.name = 'ACT_Composite' then sts.numscore end) as ACT_Composite,
  to_char (st.test_date),
  sts.numscore AS Score 
FROM students s join studenttestscore sts on s.id = sts.studentid
join studenttest st on sts.studenttestid = st.id
join test t on sts.testscoreid = ts.id
join testscore ts on ts.testid = t.id
join schools on s.schoolid = schools.school_number
WHERE t.name = 'ACT' AND sts.numscore > 0 
and s.enroll_status=0 AND s.schoolid=10
group by schools.name,
  s.lastfirst ,
  s.student_number,
  s.grade_level,
  t.name, to_char (st.test_date),sts.numscore
ORDER BY s.lastfirst,st.test_date DESC
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I ran the query but it didn't return any rows.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, and what you are trying to write is a pivot query.  Here is a corrected version.  It takes the *max* of each `CASE` expression to turn out the single row value you want.  Also, it uses proper explicit joins between all tables.  This is the preferred way of writing a modern SQL query.

```
SELECT
    sc.name AS School,
    s.lastfirst AS Student,
    s.student_number,
    s.grade_level,
    t.name AS Test_Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ts.name = 'ACT_Reading'   THEN sts.numscore end) AS ACT_Reading,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ts.name = 'ACT_Math'      THEN sts.numscore end) AS ACT_Math,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ts.name = 'ACT_English'   THEN sts.numscore end) AS ACT_English,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ts.name = 'ACT_Science'   THEN sts.numscore end) AS ACT_Science,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ts.name = 'ACT_Composite' THEN sts.numscore end) AS ACT_Composite,
    TO_CHAR(st.test_date),
    sts.numscore AS Score
FROM students s
INNER JOIN studenttestscore sts
    ON s.id = sts.studentid
INNER JOIN studenttest st
    ON sts.studenttestid = st.id
INNER JOIN test score ts
    ON sts.testscoreid = ts.id
INNER JOIN test t
    ON ts.testid = t.id
INNER JOIN schools sc
    ON s.schoolid = sc.school_number
WHERE
    t.name = 'ACT' AND
    sts.numscore > 0 AND
    s.enroll_status = 0 AND
    s.schoolid = 10
GROUP BY
    sc.name,
    s.lastfirst,
    s.student_number,
    s.grade_level,
    t.name,
    st.test_date,
    sts.numscore
ORDER BY
    s.lastfirst,
    st.test_date DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I could only get one score per row.

Comment: I'm afraid without seeing your data this is as much help as I can offer you.  If you want to take this further, then setup a demo on a site such as [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) and maybe I can have a look there.

Comment: I got it working with Alex Poole's first query. Thank you so much for your help! You were correct I needed to add MAX and the GROUP by clauses. Have a great day!